# Where is Satan?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

In my Isaac run I stumbled upon something weird...

When I entered the devil room Satan was replaced with an angel. What is this angel doing in a deal with the devil? Also is there some more meaning to it? Are there any benefits of having an angel instead of Satan?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afterbirth+ has a bunch of "weird" devil and angel rooms - I have myself encountered Satan sitting in an angel room. I'm not sure if it is an actual glitch or a legitimate room layout... however there is no "secret meaning" behind the statue swap. You can try bombing the angel statue to see if he attacks you and grants you a half key on his death (needed to fight Mega Satan), but other than that there is nothing special about these alternate rooms.

Comment: People on the subreddit have checked, and the current consensus is that you can fight the angel statue, but it will not drop the key piece, and you will also never get that key piece in the future. This is likely a bug.

Comment: @murgatroid99 the angel not dropping a key piece would be consistent with the fact that even before AB+, any angel encountered outside a "real" Angel Room (i.e. in a super-secret room with eternal hearts) didcn't drop a key piece